Can somebody explain to me what "Gekihan'ongakushu" means?
Google translate is no help and translates it as "easy to defeat", which doesn't seem right in any way.
After much struggling, I was able to find out that part of it at least should refer to music. That being "ongaku" in "Gekihan'ongakushu". But I can't figure out what this whole phrase is supposed to mean.
For reference, this comes from the Monogatari series albums. Here's an example.

It is 劇伴音楽集. To my knowledge, it's not a common word.1

劇 (theatrical) play
伴 to accompany
音楽 music
集 collection

So the whole phrase means collection of music accompanying play(anime chapters or movie), which is more commonly referred to as OST.

1 As commented and linked, a dictionary has is as げきばん(geki-ban). And 大辞林 has げきはん(geki-han). I checked 広辞苑 and 日本国語大辞典, and both do not have 劇伴 in the first place (nor other middle sized dictionaries).

Thank you so much! So, "Original Soundtrack" is actually a close approximation to the meaning of this. Google Translate has "劇伴音楽集" as "Drama music collection", that actually makes more sense. It doesn't know how to translate it unless written with Kanji. I had also tried to search for "Original Soundtrack" in Japanese but couldn't find a proper translation.

@Akaisteph7 FYI I found the original title by searching 化物語 on amazon(jp) and identified it by the cover art.

劇伴 word is in dictionary with reading with rendaku as げきばん (gekiban) and meaning "background music (in a movie, television drama, etc.)".

@Arfrever Ah right, edited. But I feel it should be 伴劇 in normal Chinese order.

スーパー大辞林 has it as げきはん.

劇伴 is fairly common in the anime industry (I believe most anime fans know it), and as far as I know, it's always read as げきばん. Wikipedia says "「げきはん」とはあまり言わない", but personally I've never heard げきはん even once.
